# Convert irregular list to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Im trying to convert a list with colons separated elements into a dictionary, but im getting error using `dict()`.

Error example:

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required`

This is an example of the list Im trying to convert:

```
['inetnum:1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname:APNIC-LABS', 'descr:APNICandCloudflareDNSResolverproject', 'descr:RoutedgloballybyAS13335/Cloudflare', 'descr:ResearchprefixforAPNICLabs', 'country:AU', 'org:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'abuse-c:AA1412-AP', 'status:ASSIGNEDPORTABLE', 'remarks:---------------', 'remarks:AllCloudflareabusereportingcanbedonevia', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/f/5b/f5bbf78a66c792df55d04ee6bce9698d5c8accaf.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@cloudflare.com', 'remarks:---------------', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-routes:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'last-modified:2020-07-15T13:10:57Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'auth:#Filtered', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.netwasvalidatedon2021-02-09', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:21Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'organisation:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'org-name:APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'country:AU', 'address:6CordeliaSt', 'phone:+61-7-38583100', 'fax-no:+61-7-38583199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-ref:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'last-modified:2017-10-11T01:28:39Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:ABUSEAPNICRANDNETAU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:ZZ', 'phone:+000000000', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'nic-hdl:AA1412-AP', 'remarks:GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-by:APNIC-ABUSE', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:22Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:APNICRESEARCH', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:AU', 'phone:+61-7-3858-3188', 'fax-no:+61-7-3858-3199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/a/4a/a4a58e14449e98257260341784a655af43ebbb08.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'nic-hdl:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AH256-AP', 'admin-c:AH256-AP', 'mnt-by:MAINT-APNIC-AP', 'last-modified:2018-04-04T04:26:04Z', 'source:APNIC', '', '', '', 'route:1.1.1.0/24', 'origin:AS13335', 'descr:APNICResearchandDevelopment', '6CordeliaSt', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2018-03-16T16:58:06Z', 'source:APNIC', '']
```

I would like to get something like:

`{"inetnum":"1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255", "netname":"APNIC-LABS"}`

What can i do?

Comment: Please post the code that is misbehaving as a [MCVE]; we're happy to help, but knowing what you're actually doing is helpful for explaining what's wrong. It would also be helpful to know what the expected behavior is for input strings with zero colons, or more than one colon in them; do you split only on the first colon and treat the rest as unimportant, discard them, or something else?

Comment: You have multiple strings starting with 'remarks:'. How do you propose to handle them?

Comment: What's "irregular" about your list?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` method on `:` to separate the strings in your list into key-value pairs for the dict.

```
res = {}
data = ['inetnum:1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname:APNIC-LABS', 'descr:APNICandCloudflareDNSResolverproject', 'descr:RoutedgloballybyAS13335/Cloudflare', 'descr:ResearchprefixforAPNICLabs', 'country:AU', 'org:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'abuse-c:AA1412-AP', 'status:ASSIGNEDPORTABLE', 'remarks:---------------', 'remarks:AllCloudflareabusereportingcanbedonevia', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/f/5b/f5bbf78a66c792df55d04ee6bce9698d5c8accaf.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@cloudflare.com', 'remarks:---------------', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-routes:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'last-modified:2020-07-15T13:10:57Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'auth:#Filtered', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.netwasvalidatedon2021-02-09', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:21Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'organisation:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'org-name:APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'country:AU', 'address:6CordeliaSt', 'phone:+61-7-38583100', 'fax-no:+61-7-38583199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-ref:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'last-modified:2017-10-11T01:28:39Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:ABUSEAPNICRANDNETAU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:ZZ', 'phone:+000000000', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'nic-hdl:AA1412-AP', 'remarks:GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-by:APNIC-ABUSE', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:22Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:APNICRESEARCH', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:AU', 'phone:+61-7-3858-3188', 'fax-no:+61-7-3858-3199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/a/4a/a4a58e14449e98257260341784a655af43ebbb08.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'nic-hdl:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AH256-AP', 'admin-c:AH256-AP', 'mnt-by:MAINT-APNIC-AP', 'last-modified:2018-04-04T04:26:04Z', 'source:APNIC', '', '', '', 'route:1.1.1.0/24', 'origin:AS13335', 'descr:APNICResearchandDevelopment', '6CordeliaSt', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2018-03-16T16:58:06Z', 'source:APNIC', '']

for entry in data:
    try:
        k, v = entry.split(':')
        res[k] = v
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(res)
```

Of note, you have one entry `'6CordeliaSt'` that is neither separated by a colon, nor a blank string. Tweaking the code further would depend on whether or not you wanted to keep or ignore this entry (the above code will ignore it).

I also noticed that you have several entries that start with `'remarks'`, so this code above will only maintain the last one. A more complex solution would be to keep a list as the value of each dictionary key and append to it, like so

```
for entry in data:
    try:
        k, v = entry.split(':')
        if k in res.keys():
            res[k].append(v)
        else:
            res[k] = [v]
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(res)
```

This will still ignore strings that aren't split on a colon like 6CordeliaSt, but it will keep all values together that start with the same key, like `remarks`, but your "simpler" entries will need to be accessed via the list

```
{
    "inetnum": ["1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255"], 
    "netname": ["APNIC-LABS"],
    "remarks": ['---------------', 'AllCloudflareabusereportingcanbedonevia', '<imgsrc="/eimg/f/5b/f5bbf78a66c792df55d04ee6bce9698d5c8accaf.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@cloudflare.com', '---------------', '<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.netwasvalidatedon2021-02-09', 'GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU']
}
```

Comment: `if entry:` won't work because `''` isn't a `NoneType`. `type('')` returns `class<str>`

Comment: @chemicalwill Not quite. An empty string is not a NoneType but it is 'falsy'

Comment: @AlbertWinestein true, but using `if entry` in my example still raises a `ValueError`

Comment: Did you try running this code?  It raises a `ValueError`.

Comment: @chemicalwill Have you considered what would happen if a non-empty string in the list did **not** contain a colon?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein I had tried it on a smaller subset. it should work now. of note there is one entry "6CordeliaSt" that is neither separated by a semicolon or a blank string. I'm not sure if that's relevant to the OP

Comment: Did you try running the updated version of the code?  It has a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @Samwise Except block got caught by auto-capitalization

Comment: You also don't need the `if entry != ''` with the `try/except` since `''` will raise the same `ValueError` as the other invalid strings.

Comment: @Samwise thanks for the catch--missed that

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to ignore the list elements that don't follow the `key:value` format, filter to those that only contain one colon:

```
>>> data = ['inetnum:1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname:APNIC-LABS', 'descr:APNICandCloudflareDNSResolverproject', 'descr:RoutedgloballybyAS13335/Cloudflare', 'descr:ResearchprefixforAPNICLabs', 'country:AU', 'org:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'abuse-c:AA1412-AP', 'status:ASSIGNEDPORTABLE', 'remarks:---------------', 'remarks:AllCloudflareabusereportingcanbedonevia', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/f/5b/f5bbf78a66c792df55d04ee6bce9698d5c8accaf.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@cloudflare.com', 'remarks:---------------', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-routes:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'last-modified:2020-07-15T13:10:57Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'auth:#Filtered', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.netwasvalidatedon2021-02-09', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:21Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'organisation:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'org-name:APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'country:AU', 'address:6CordeliaSt', 'phone:+61-7-38583100', 'fax-no:+61-7-38583199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-ref:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'last-modified:2017-10-11T01:28:39Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:ABUSEAPNICRANDNETAU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:ZZ', 'phone:+000000000', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'nic-hdl:AA1412-AP', 'remarks:GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-by:APNIC-ABUSE', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:22Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:APNICRESEARCH', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:AU', 'phone:+61-7-3858-3188', 'fax-no:+61-7-3858-3199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/a/4a/a4a58e14449e98257260341784a655af43ebbb08.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'nic-hdl:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AH256-AP', 'admin-c:AH256-AP', 'mnt-by:MAINT-APNIC-AP', 'last-modified:2018-04-04T04:26:04Z', 'source:APNIC', '', '', '', 'route:1.1.1.0/24', 'origin:AS13335', 'descr:APNICResearchandDevelopment', '6CordeliaSt', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2018-03-16T16:58:06Z', 'source:APNIC', '']
>>> dict(i.split(":") for i in data if i.count(":") == 1)
{'inetnum': '1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname': 'APNIC-LABS', 'descr': 'APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'country': 'AU', 'org': 'ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'admin-c': 'AH256-AP', 'tech-c': 'AH256-AP', 'abuse-c': 'AA1412-AP', 'status': 'ASSIGNEDPORTABLE', 'remarks': 'GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'mnt-by': 'MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-routes': 'MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-irt': 'IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'source': 'APNIC', 'irt': 'IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'address': 'Australia', 'e-mail': '<imgsrc="/eimg/a/4a/a4a58e14449e98257260341784a655af43ebbb08.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'abuse-mailbox': '<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'auth': '#Filtered', 'organisation': 'ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'org-name': 'APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'phone': '+61-7-3858-3188', 'fax-no': '+61-7-3858-3199', 'mnt-ref': 'APNIC-HM', 'role': 'APNICRESEARCH', 'nic-hdl': 'AR302-AP', 'route': '1.1.1.0/24', 'origin': 'AS13335'}
```

Without that `if i.count(":") == 1` filter, you get errors on some of the strings because some of them are empty (hence they have length 0 when split) and at least one has three `:`s (hence it has length 4).

Note that this solution simply ignores those entries rather than trying to make sense of them or raise an error.  If you wanted to do something else with the 3-`:` entries (like split them into two key-value pairs, or allow for keys and/or values to contain `:` characters) you'd need to settle on an approach and modify the way that the key:value sequence is built.

Comment: A reasonable way to handle any of the inputs, with 0-n colons, would be to use `.partition(':')` to get an unconditional three-tuple. Would not split on second and later colons, and would map stuff without a colon to the empty string. Depends on OP's needs.

Comment: @chemicalwill: What concatenation?

Comment: @ShadowRanger iterating within the `dict()` call

Comment: @chemicalwill: There's no concatenation there. I think you may need to look up the definition of concatenation. Are you referring to the generator expression (which performs no concatenation, but is sometimes referred to as a generator *comprehension* given the similarity to list comprehensions)?

Comment: @ShadowRanger definitely meant comprehension, apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular `for` loop for readability. Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split on `:` into a maximum of 2 elements. Skip strings where no `:` is found.

```
lst = ['inetnum:1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname:APNIC-LABS', 'descr:APNICandCloudflareDNSResolverproject', 'descr:RoutedgloballybyAS13335/Cloudflare', 'descr:ResearchprefixforAPNICLabs', 'country:AU', 'org:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'abuse-c:AA1412-AP', 'status:ASSIGNEDPORTABLE', 'remarks:---------------', 'remarks:AllCloudflareabusereportingcanbedonevia', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/f/5b/f5bbf78a66c792df55d04ee6bce9698d5c8accaf.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@cloudflare.com', 'remarks:---------------', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-routes:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'last-modified:2020-07-15T13:10:57Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'auth:#Filtered', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.netwasvalidatedon2021-02-09', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:21Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'organisation:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'org-name:APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'country:AU', 'address:6CordeliaSt', 'phone:+61-7-38583100', 'fax-no:+61-7-38583199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-ref:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'last-modified:2017-10-11T01:28:39Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:ABUSEAPNICRANDNETAU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:ZZ', 'phone:+000000000', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'nic-hdl:AA1412-AP', 'remarks:GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-by:APNIC-ABUSE', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:22Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:APNICRESEARCH', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:AU', 'phone:+61-7-3858-3188', 'fax-no:+61-7-3858-3199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/a/4a/a4a58e14449e98257260341784a655af43ebbb08.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'nic-hdl:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AH256-AP', 'admin-c:AH256-AP', 'mnt-by:MAINT-APNIC-AP', 'last-modified:2018-04-04T04:26:04Z', 'source:APNIC', '', '', '', 'route:1.1.1.0/24', 'origin:AS13335', 'descr:APNICResearchandDevelopment', '6CordeliaSt', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2018-03-16T16:58:06Z', 'source:APNIC', '']

dct = {}

for s in lst:
    tup = s.split(':', maxsplit=1)
    if len(tup) < 2:
        continue
    else:
        dct[tup[0]] = tup[1]

print(dct)
# {'inetnum': '1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname': 'APNIC-LABS', 'descr': 'APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'country': 'AU', 'org': 'ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'admin-c': 'AH256-AP', 'tech-c': 'AH256-AP', 'abuse-c': 'AA1412-AP', 'status': 'ASSIGNEDPORTABLE', 'remarks': 'GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'mnt-by': 'MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-routes': 'MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-irt': 'IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'last-modified': '2018-03-16T16:58:06Z', 'source': 'APNIC', 'irt': 'IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'address': 'Australia', 'e-mail': '<imgsrc="/eimg/a/4a/a4a58e14449e98257260341784a655af43ebbb08.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'abuse-mailbox': '<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'auth': '#Filtered', 'organisation': 'ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'org-name': 'APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'phone': '+61-7-3858-3188', 'fax-no': '+61-7-3858-3199', 'mnt-ref': 'APNIC-HM', 'role': 'APNICRESEARCH', 'nic-hdl': 'AR302-AP', 'route': '1.1.1.0/24', 'origin': 'AS13335'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator as the input to a *dict()* constructor has been shown to good effect by @Samwise

Here's a simple loop that might be easier to understand:

```
list_ = ['inetnum:1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname:APNIC-LABS', 'descr:APNICandCloudflareDNSResolverproject', 'descr:RoutedgloballybyAS13335/Cloudflare', 'descr:ResearchprefixforAPNICLabs', 'country:AU', 'org:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'abuse-c:AA1412-AP', 'status:ASSIGNEDPORTABLE', 'remarks:---------------', 'remarks:AllCloudflareabusereportingcanbedonevia', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/f/5b/f5bbf78a66c792df55d04ee6bce9698d5c8accaf.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@cloudflare.com', 'remarks:---------------', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-routes:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'last-modified:2020-07-15T13:10:57Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'auth:#Filtered', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.netwasvalidatedon2021-02-09', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:21Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'organisation:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'org-name:APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'country:AU', 'address:6CordeliaSt', 'phone:+61-7-38583100', 'fax-no:+61-7-38583199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-ref:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'last-modified:2017-10-11T01:28:39Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:ABUSEAPNICRANDNETAU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:ZZ', 'phone:+000000000', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'nic-hdl:AA1412-AP', 'remarks:GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-by:APNIC-ABUSE', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:22Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:APNICRESEARCH', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:AU', 'phone:+61-7-3858-3188', 'fax-no:+61-7-3858-3199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/a/4a/a4a58e14449e98257260341784a655af43ebbb08.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'nic-hdl:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AH256-AP', 'admin-c:AH256-AP', 'mnt-by:MAINT-APNIC-AP', 'last-modified:2018-04-04T04:26:04Z', 'source:APNIC', '', '', '', 'route:1.1.1.0/24', 'origin:AS13335', 'descr:APNICResearchandDevelopment', '6CordeliaSt', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2018-03-16T16:58:06Z', 'source:APNIC', '']

dict_ = {}

for e in list_:
    k, *v = e.split(':', 1)
    if v:
        dict_[k] = v[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that:

1. Does not discard entries with multiple colons (treats all colons after the first as part of the value)
2. Can be easily tweaked to choose what to do with entries without colons, without needing exception handling (that would make a comprehension not work)

To avoid a (slower) inner genexpr, it uses `map` with a preconstructed partitioner:

```
# At top of file
from operator import methodcaller  # Efficient means of invoking .partition(':') on each item
PART_COLON= methodcaller('partition', ':')

# At point of use:
mylist = ['inetnum:1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname:APNIC-LABS', 'descr:APNICandCloudflareDNSResolverproject', 'descr:RoutedgloballybyAS13335/Cloudflare', 'descr:ResearchprefixforAPNICLabs', 'country:AU', 'org:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'abuse-c:AA1412-AP', 'status:ASSIGNEDPORTABLE', 'remarks:---------------', 'remarks:AllCloudflareabusereportingcanbedonevia', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/f/5b/f5bbf78a66c792df55d04ee6bce9698d5c8accaf.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@cloudflare.com', 'remarks:---------------', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-routes:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'mnt-irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'last-modified:2020-07-15T13:10:57Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'irt:IRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'auth:#Filtered', 'remarks:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.netwasvalidatedon2021-02-09', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:21Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'organisation:ORG-ARAD1-AP', 'org-name:APNICResearchandDevelopment', 'country:AU', 'address:6CordeliaSt', 'phone:+61-7-38583100', 'fax-no:+61-7-38583199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-ref:APNIC-HM', 'mnt-by:APNIC-HM', 'last-modified:2017-10-11T01:28:39Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:ABUSEAPNICRANDNETAU', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:ZZ', 'phone:+000000000', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'admin-c:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AR302-AP', 'nic-hdl:AA1412-AP', 'remarks:GeneratedfromirtobjectIRT-APNICRANDNET-AU', 'abuse-mailbox:<imgsrc="/eimg/b/11/b116938aa3180504ab727885fc8426ee57dbb10b.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'mnt-by:APNIC-ABUSE', 'last-modified:2021-03-09T01:10:22Z', 'source:APNIC', '', 'role:APNICRESEARCH', 'address:POBox3646', 'address:SouthBrisbane,QLD4101', 'address:Australia', 'country:AU', 'phone:+61-7-3858-3188', 'fax-no:+61-7-3858-3199', 'e-mail:<imgsrc="/eimg/a/4a/a4a58e14449e98257260341784a655af43ebbb08.png"class="email"alt="email"loading="lazy">@apnic.net', 'nic-hdl:AR302-AP', 'tech-c:AH256-AP', 'admin-c:AH256-AP', 'mnt-by:MAINT-APNIC-AP', 'last-modified:2018-04-04T04:26:04Z', 'source:APNIC', '', '', '', 'route:1.1.1.0/24', 'origin:AS13335', 'descr:APNICResearchandDevelopment', '6CordeliaSt', 'mnt-by:MAINT-AU-APNIC-GM85-AP', 'last-modified:2018-03-16T16:58:06Z', 'source:APNIC', '']

mydict = {k: v for k, _, v in map(PART_COLON, mylist) if k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVdbU@s2EH7Pr9CEBzhTlFi@xdGUTg3JAWYg0CS80OmckWU5UbElj6ykpJ3@dirlQi4QDqfTljrJ2N6LvN799tOmnOmxFN7T0wGINdCyBDIDGc9ZLVOyALJkimipAC9KqTQomDFPKclzpgA4AN0s45QzYTVEVNaZi6l84GIEGiVRmmsuxdEhPvwEpACM0DHgmhW127g//HJ2c3XTO9la9Ojw2evwGFi/Wm0eWim5eYpZf1IxXCtmOa80OAE/H3LBtJgUGDXsx4GLsxsE1t/qSMFwfNu7PINX8enASlNWUbWQEZGe5XKSZjlRrNMb9Fkl8ylTpZK/MqrX1n050Swd5TIxcc6SWTxAnucFzbX3hi2rGFF0XCqW8cdMqvmjrkhSWRsqJ0KrGY7v7J1UI3zTP4dxP@4gGN9aGUkLLiDFcd9z3KVMMzreEZHE5MLKYuSjlbDSRE8qHA8Gl@e9buf2pj@MT6@6VqVYQdRDheH2samK83z9QvP1FbOFN/WkRCQslYJNOdl0@Z4Xo0rRk3qTmatm1gySZhYkSdaKSBjSVttNsyBIHZ@xMKGsHbajNKARoZRkjVKM6jQnVXVSN8vxvE5yvbrMJUnNc0/qOfl9Vv/hR/ocWIPK4isvVAgNk9my7hfXK5GyVazwdXzZG8L4Di7059dRsEyfNeJK48v@cKHsx71Or2uNrdqEqmEhU55xlmLXcR3otCAKhsjDyMFB635eAzlRdAk6e29/byxK0lSxqsK3N6fy0Qv9cFM4MBGPTxWvEiLY8U9XHR85aNMgnlRakXxRFAZt6nZrkjQRaiYIhW0vIsRDkRM4PklabiuKgoxGvhsyFrTSJEFO8k01IaXgtGG6bI1Ha5fIx4@K4Z2tY5KKDz7zXBuAp2/A@T8I@zdSTU39UqJtexlMIWjidNobMN6P1xeANM6ecR46yALSRXsBaYiHCF4RS7UvGMgo4Zo4V3xmyLLDpiyXZWEo/yWXrSAZnkmVMgPJwdyoNDsMw9@FCLagFwWRhxzHyjPyCIXcUrTbH47iOU2w7AV17LDJbuKRoQGz@SCbeDfCXntv4pXMjeT0btDd5IJ/nApWpbm/36iBszo@nize16jGA47TfHuPW/XqORN2PGGpnVUMwcrE7tn7WPZ/wE5bOJpD4D097H4FSvN37Ro49c8u/iUQLVK428jQJCp6tZPh261Mmj5pEp8EEUO@77dZO3KDlhs6no9akU/CICCZ77EkSZzo76f7GTyvYOzCDcLdcWtDtk28i3q9Srgogo5vvkPHx26IHX9vsdZFMzPIalxtuv6Cb/mIC7wcKndm1P30u0O037xb2OA9iMIhCnEQYSd8PfhfambgTjm1A/cfDxhMgZlpwcMx@HJsrrkABSmP1hP9MViM558Az8DDn0/L/w5lqcwIX1ucGovT0WLdT09/AQ)

As written, this only discards entries with an empty key (which happens when the string is empty or it begins with a `:`), while keeping keys with no values (because they end with the only `:` in the string or there is no `:`). It's trivial to tweak behavior though:

1. Discard inputs with an empty key or no colon at all: `mydict = {k: v for k, sep, v in map(PART_COLON, mylist) if k and sep}`
2. Discard inputs with empty keys *or* values (even if they end with a colon): `mydict = {k: v for k, _, v in map(PART_COLON, mylist) if k and v}`
3. Discard entries without a colon, but if there is no data after the colon, store `None` instead of the empty string: `mydict = {k: (v or None) for k, sep, v in map(PART_COLON, mylist) if k and sep}`

etc. You'll always have anything before the first colon in `k` (empty only if the string starts with `:`, containing the whole string if `:` doesn't appear in the string), `sep` (or `_` when I'm ignoring it) will be either `':'` (at least one colon in the string) or `''` (no colon in the string), and `v` will be all remaining data after the first colon (if one exists), and empty when there is no colon (or the colon was the last character in the string; you distinguish the cases based on `sep` being empty/non-empty).

It's efficient (`map` moves the inner partitioning loop to the C layer entirely, the outer `dict` comprehension is specially optimized in the bytecode interpreter), compact, exception-free (the input must be an iterable of `str`, but the values of the `str`s won't cause unpacking failures like `.split(':')` would when the number of commas is variable from 0 to n) and extremely configurable (as shown, just tiny tweaks to the filter condition do most of the work, possibly with tweaks to the output expression to replace certain values, e.g. the empty string with `None`.

Answer (score -3):

for exemple you can try this code plz my bro

```
list =['inetnum:1.1.1.0-1.1.1.255', 'netname:APNIC-LABS','']

d = {}
for x in list :
    if ':' in x :
        d[x.split(":", 1)[0]] = x.split(":", 1)[1]
        
print(d)
```

Comment: Please only post tested and properly formatted code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).